# Deny passing variable through link

Tags: php

```
$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->prop1 = 1;
$obj->prop2 = 2;
$a1 = array(
    0 => $obj,
    1 => $obj,
);
$a2 = $a1;
$a1[0]->prop1 = 100;
var_dump($a2);
```

Current result:

```
$a2 = array(
    0 => stdClass::__set_state(array(
        'prop1' => 100,
        'prop2' => 2
    )),
    1 => stdClass::__set_state(array(
        'prop1' => 100,
        'prop2' => 2
    ))
);
```

Required result:

```
$a2 = array(
    0 => stdClass::__set_state(array(
        'prop1' => 1,
        'prop2' => 2
    )),
    1 => stdClass::__set_state(array(
        'prop1' => 1,
        'prop2' => 2
    ))
);
```

**PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function deepClone(array $input) {
    $output = array();
    foreach($input as $key => $obj) {
        $output[$key] = clone $obj;
    }

    return $output;
}

$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->prop1 = 1;
$obj->prop2 = 2;
$a1 = array(
    0 => $obj,
    1 => $obj,
);
$a2 = deepClone($a1);
$a1[0]->prop1 = 100;
var_dump($a2);
```

But I feel that you should come up with a different approach to whatever your problem is, as I tend to avoid `clone` as much as possible.